# How can i do this symbol = | in centos console virtualbox?

Tags: console, centos, symbols

I NEED TO DO THIS :

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

but i can't do this symbol " | "

how can i ?

Comment: What do you mean you can't |?

Comment: i can't do the symbol |  in console virtualbox - centos, pipe symbol is the name if i remember